# How can I save a form's data (which contains multiple Knockout view models) without submitting so that it can be completed later?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a form long enough that I want to enable users to save their progress and finish it later. It has multiple Knockout view models (all grids) as well as good old-fashioned inputs.

**Here's an example of the code powering one of the grids (they're all basically the same):**

```
/**
 * Goals
 * @param {string} goal_secondary          value of input[name=goal_secondary]
 * @param {string} relation_goal_secondary value of textarea[name=relation_goal_secondary]
 */
function Goal(goal_secondary, relation_goal_secondary) {
  var self = this;

  self.goal_secondary          = goal_secondary;
  self.relation_goal_secondary = relation_goal_secondary;
}

function GoalsVM() {
  var self = this;

  // Apparently moves trigger afterAdd, but I don't want it to, so let's pretend it doesn't.
  move = false;

  self.goals = ko.observableArray([
    new Goal('', '')
  ]);

  self.addGoal = function() {
    self.goals.push(new Goal('', ''));
  }
  self.removeGoal = function(goal) {
    self.goals.remove(goal);
  }

  self.afterAdd = function(el) {
    // Don't do this stuff on move!
    if (el.nodeType === 1 && !move) {
      $(el).hide().slideDown();
    }
    // Reset move in case the user's next action is to add a new goal.
    move = false;
  }
  self.beforeMove = function(el) {
    // Tell afterAdd this is a move, not really an add.
    move = true;
  }
  self.beforeRemove = function(el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 1) {
      $(el).slideUp(function() {
        $(el).remove();
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**Here's the associated markup:**

```
<ul class="grid list-unstyled"
    data-bind="sortable: {
      data: goals,
      afterAdd: afterAdd,
      beforeRemove: beforeRemove,
      beforeMove: beforeMove
    }">
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="move">&equiv;</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input class="form-control"
             data-bind="value: goal_secondary,
                        attr: { name: 'goal_secondary_' + $index() }">

      <textarea rows="3" class="form-control"
                data-bind="value: relation_goal_secondary,
                           attr: { name: 'relation_goal_secondary_' + $index() }"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <button class="btn text-danger btn-xs remove" data-bind="click: removeGoal">
        &times;
      </button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I was trying to follow the [Loading and Saving JSON data](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) page in the docs, but `ko.toJSON(GoalsVM)` returns `undefined`.

I also tried using `var Goal = function(goal_secondary, relation_goal_secondary) {…}` and `var GoalsVM = function() {…}`, but I still got `undefined`.

Comment: I put your code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdp4g/) as a starting point. The `toJSON` works fine. Where are you trying to "save" the data.

Comment: Strange. I'll have to see what might be interfering with `toJSON` locally. As for where to save, I was thinking I'd write to a `.json` file named by another field in the form. Then the user could load it again by entering that file name.

Comment: I'm also using jQuery (v2.0.3), jQuery Sortable (UI v1.10.3), and Knockout Sortable(v0.8.4), and I think the issue lies in there somewhere. I'm trying to bring the changes you made into my local env, but I'm getting this error: `Message: beforeMove is not defined`.